# Cannot find classes from imported module during maven build

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, dependency-management

I am working on a module in a project that's to convert old data structure to match updated data structure. Since most of the methods and classes required for said conversion have already been implemented in a prior module in the same project, I added the prior module as a dependency in the new module.
It works, as I can access the required classes and their public methods. However, when I run 'mvn clean install' to build the new module, the new module's build fails with errors about not finding the imported classes.

Here is the parent pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--suppress MavenModelInspection -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.hcb.migration.bioenrol</groupId>
    <artifactId>hcb-migration-bienrol</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.0</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.build.resourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.resourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>abis-migrations-imports</module>
        <module>abis-migrations-export</module>
        <module>abis-migrations-conversion</module>
        <module>runtime-migrations-export</module>
        <module>runtime-migrations-conversion</module>
        <module>runtime-migrations-import</module>

    </modules>
    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <!-- This repo requires credentials from your ~/.m2/settings.xml -->
            <id>archiva-snapshot-repo</id>
            <name>hcb-snapshot-repo</name>
            <url>http://archiva.hcb:8080/repository/archiva-snapshot-repo/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <!-- This repo requires credentials from your ~/.m2/settings.xml -->
            <id>archiva-release-repo</id>
            <name>hcb-release-repo</name>
            <url>http://archiva.hcb:8080/repository/archiva-release-repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <!-- This repo requires credentials from your ~/.m2/settings.xml -->
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>archiva-snapshot-repo</id>
            <name>hcb-snapshot-repo</name>
            <url>http://archiva.hcb:8080/repository/archiva-snapshot-repo/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <!-- This repo requires credentials from your ~/.m2/settings.xml -->
            <id>archiva-release-repo</id>
            <name>hcb-release-repo</name>
            <url>http://archiva.hcb:8080/repository/archiva-release-repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

This is the pom file of the older module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>hcb-migration-bienrol</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.hcb.migration.bioenrol</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <artifactId>abis-migrations-conversion</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- MMABIS client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hcb.3rdparty.libs</groupId>
            <artifactId>neurotec-abis-client-management-rest</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hcb.services.bioenroll</groupId>
            <artifactId>bioenroll-inf</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
<!--            Add class with main method to manifest-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion.AbisExportConverter</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is the pom file of the module I am working on whose build fails:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>hcb-migration-bienrol</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.hcb.migration.bioenrol</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>runtime-migrations-conversion</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hcb.migration.bioenrol</groupId>
            <artifactId>abis-migrations-conversion</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.hcb.runtime.migrations.conversion.RuntimeConversionApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is the build error:

```
[INFO] 45 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  12.418 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-01-20T12:23:07+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project runtime-migrations-conversion: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[4,46] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[5,46] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[6,46] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[7,46] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[8,56] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion.exception does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[9,52] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion.pojos does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[10,52] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion.pojos does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[11,52] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion.pojos does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[12,52] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion.pojos does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[13,52] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[27,59] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[31,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class DirectoryUtils
[ERROR]   location: class com.hcb.runtime.migrations.conversion.pojo.RConversionSubInfo
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[32,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ConversionDemograhpicsInfo
[ERROR]   location: class com.hcb.runtime.migrations.conversion.pojo.RConversionSubInfo
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[33,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ConversionFaceInfo
[ERROR]   location: class com.hcb.runtime.migrations.conversion.pojo.RConversionSubInfo
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[34,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ConversionPrintInfo
[ERROR]   location: class com.hcb.runtime.migrations.conversion.pojo.RConversionSubInfo
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[35,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ConversionIrisInfo
[ERROR]   location: class com.hcb.runtime.migrations.conversion.pojo.RConversionSubInfo
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[39,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class SubjectDemographicsConverter
[ERROR]   location: class com.hcb.runtime.migrations.conversion.pojo.RConversionSubInfo
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[44,74] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class SubjectDemographicsConverter
[ERROR]   location: class com.hcb.runtime.migrations.conversion.pojo.RConversionSubInfo
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[50,42] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ConversionException
[ERROR]   location: class com.hcb.runtime.migrations.conversion.pojo.RConversionSubInfo
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[63,42] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ConversionException
[ERROR]   location: class com.hcb.runtime.migrations.conversion.pojo.RConversionSubInfo
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[95,35] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class SubjectDemographicsConverter
[ERROR]   location: class com.hcb.runtime.migrations.conversion.pojo.RConversionSubInfo
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[95,101] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ConversionException
[ERROR]   location: class com.hcb.runtime.migrations.conversion.pojo.RConversionSubInfo
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[171,43] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ConversionException
[ERROR]   location: class com.hcb.runtime.migrations.conversion.pojo.RConversionSubInfo
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[205,43] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ConversionException
[ERROR]   location: class com.hcb.runtime.migrations.conversion.pojo.RConversionSubInfo
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/pojo/RConversionSubInfo.java:[238,12] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ConversionDemograhpicsInfo
[ERROR]   location: class com.hcb.runtime.migrations.conversion.pojo.RConversionSubInfo
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/RConvertedRecordInfo.java:[7,56] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion.exception does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/RConvertedRecordInfo.java:[8,52] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/RConvertedRecordInfo.java:[25,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class DirectoryUtils
[ERROR]   location: class com.hcb.runtime.migrations.conversion.RConvertedRecordInfo
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/RConvertedRecordInfo.java:[63,69] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ConversionException
[ERROR]   location: class com.hcb.runtime.migrations.conversion.RConvertedRecordInfo
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/RuntimeConversionApplication.java:[3,56] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion.exception does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/RuntimeConversionApplication.java:[4,54] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion.network does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/RuntimeConversionApplication.java:[5,54] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion.network does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/RuntimeConversionApplication.java:[6,61] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion.network.config does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/RuntimeConversionApplication.java:[18,51] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ConversionException
[ERROR]   location: class com.hcb.runtime.migrations.conversion.RuntimeConversionApplication
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/RuntimeConversionImpl.java:[3,46] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/RuntimeConversionImpl.java:[4,56] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion.exception does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/RuntimeConversionImpl.java:[5,54] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion.network does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/RuntimeConversionImpl.java:[6,54] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion.network does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/RuntimeConversionImpl.java:[7,52] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/RuntimeConversionImpl.java:[15,59] package com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/RuntimeConversionImpl.java:[15,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/RuntimeConversionImpl.java:[19,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class SubjectDemographicsConverter
[ERROR]   location: class com.hcb.runtime.migrations.conversion.RuntimeConversionImpl
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/RuntimeConversionImpl.java:[22,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class EnrolmentAPI
[ERROR]   location: class com.hcb.runtime.migrations.conversion.RuntimeConversionImpl
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/RuntimeConversionImpl.java:[22,61] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ConfigurationAPI
[ERROR]   location: class com.hcb.runtime.migrations.conversion.RuntimeConversionImpl
[ERROR] /C:/Users/ikechukwua/IdeaProjects/migration-bioenrol/runtime-migrations-conversion/src/main/java/com/hcb/runtime/migrations/conversion/RuntimeConversionImpl.java:[26,80] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ConversionException
[ERROR]   location: class com.hcb.runtime.migrations.conversion.RuntimeConversionImpl
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I have checked that they're both accounted for in the parent pom, I also ensured that the older module built successfully with 'mvn clean install' before trying to build the module where it is used as a dependency.

Comment: It seems maven can't find the package `com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion` in the poms. Are you sure you have included it?

Comment: Did you `mvn install`ed the required dependency before?

Comment: @mrxaxen, yes it is included in the older module. 

PS: Excuse the late reply please, been very unwell.

Comment: @ValerijDobler, yes I did this first before building the new module.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the error. Found out that the module I intend on importing as a dependency when built with mvn clean install, does not build correctly in the first place because:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
<!--            Add class with main method to manifest-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.hcb.neurotec.migrations.conversion.AbisExportConverter</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

The module is not a spring project, so when the build gets to this block of code, it encounters issues that aren't surprisingly flagged. Removing this block in the old module allowed the new module build successfully.